# Does android studio have live debug like visual studio does and where

Tags: android, android-studio

i have android studio 4.1.3 and i'm wondering if it has a setting that i can change so i can see debug in real time. I'm currently using visual studio which tells me in console where i'm wrong as i'm typing. I'm typing the code in vs and then pasting into android studio but it's getting tiresome especially if i have a lot of screens. Is there an easy way that i'm missing? And yes i have tried to google the question already so please don't tell me to google.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, android Studio does not currently have a live debug feature.
You do have a debug option on the top right corner of the screen if you need it.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know android studio can't do it. I thought i was missing something. I will keep coding in visual studio and then copying over to android studio.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what i was looking for is the "Dart Analysis". It's located at the very bottom next to the "terminal" button. I've tested and i see if i change something, it immediately notifies me in the "Dart Analysis window"